# Visual studio build order working with nugets

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

Given a solution A that has 2 projects: 1,2 -

let's assume that project 2 depends on project 1.

Now , if we use a project references - than VS/MSBuild can resolve the correct build order and will always build project 1 before project 2.

But, what if we want to use Nugets to manage the dependencies?
Now project 2 defines that it depends on "nuget 1".
But it doesn't look like MSBuild is aware of this.
Is there any way to resolve this , without defining manually the build order in each solution?

Comment: You are challenging the design of MSBuild and NuGet, so you should go to their GitHub repo, not here.

Comment: Well , actually I'm not trying to challenge their design, just trying to understand what's the correct way to work with it. Will also try to ask there

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to resolve this , without defining manually the build order in each solution?

Just as Lex Li mentioned, it`s the design of MSBuild and NuGet. When we use NuGets to manage the dependencies, MSBuild will build the dependence "nuget 1" first, it will work according to nuget design, find and download the dependence rather than build and generate the project 1.

In order to be able to get the dependence "nuget 1", we **have to** build the project 1 manually first, otherwise, MSBuild will throw an exception that could not find the dependence.

**All of those are related to the design of NuGet, find and download the dependence rather than build and generate.**

Hope this can help you.